# Android - JNI / NDK - crash with SIGSEV - signal handling not triggered

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have Android native C++ code. However, sometimes when I send app to background and back, it crash with `SIGSEGV`. I want to debug it using my own signal handling and print stack trace, however, when this error occurs, my signal handling is not triggered at all.

To `JNI_OnLoad` method, I have added:

```
struct sigaction sighandler;
memset (&sighandler, '\0', sizeof(sighandler));   
sighandler.sa_sigaction = &android_sigaction;
sighandler.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

int watched_signals[] = { SIGABRT, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, SIGINT, SIGKILL };
for(int signal : watched_signals)
{
    sigaction(signal, &sighandler, &old_sa[signal]);
}
```

And I have:

```
static struct sigaction old_sa[NSIG];

static void android_sigaction(int signal, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    MY_LOG("Sending PID: %ld, UID: %ld\n", (long)siginfo->si_pid, (long)siginfo->si_uid);

    old_sa[signal].sa_handler(signal);
}
```

However, `android_sigaction` is never trigerred for the error, when app goes from background. I have tried to create bug in code (writing outside array bounds), trigger it with button push and the callback is correctly called.
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Android 5.0+ device, your problem may be caused by ART. It exposes own `signal()` and [`sigaction()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/sigchainlib/sigchain.cc#284) so it has a chance to steal signal and pass it somewhere else.
For debugging purposes you could try direct syscall:

```
for(int signal : watched_signals)
{
    syscall(_NR_sigaction, signal, &sighandler, &old_sa[signal]);
}
```

So now your handler goes directly to kernel and ART shouldn't change it.
Of course it is OK only for debugging. If you want to go with this for a prod - you need to develop some logic that will respect previous handler.

P.S. also checking returned value and `errno` is a good idea as well.

Comment: @Segio What is _NR_sigaction ?

Comment: It is syscal number that corresponds to `sigaction`. Include `<sys/syscall.h>` to get it.

Comment: Ok... it helped, but i have to add one undescroe "__NR_sigaction"